# I see an incorrect pid

Tags: linux, command, pid, gnu-screen, bin

I have a problem in my script, when I want to save the pid, then the incorrect pid is saved to me.
I suspect that the pid script (start.sh) is written to me instead of the screen command.

```
echo "Trwa uruchamianie bota muzycznego..."
    if [ -e "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
        if [ ! -x "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
            echo "${BINARYNAME} is not executable, trying to set it"
            chmod u+x "${BINARYNAME}"
        fi
        if [ -x "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LIBRARYPATH}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"                  
            screen -dmS "${BASENAME}" mono "${BINARYNAME}" > /dev/null &
            TEST=$0
            PID=$!
            echo "${PID}"
            ps -p ${PID} > /dev/null 2>&1
            if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
                echo "Bot muzyczy nie został uruchomiony."
            else
                echo $PID > TS3AudioBot.pid
                echo "Bot muzyczny został uruchomiony."
            fi
        else
            echo "${BINARNAME} nie jest możliwy do wykrycia, nie można uruchomić bota muzycznego."
        fi
    else
        echo "Could not find binary, aborting"
        exit 5
    fi
```

Comment: did you check  your code at https://shellcheck.net ? Good luck.

Comment: looks like it should be `$!` not `$$!` anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were expecting to get the pid of a *screen* process in $PID.  What's happening is that screen exits immediately, and $! refers to the pid of the vanished screen process rather than the detached process that is running your *mono* command (if it's still running).

I substituted "sleep 2000 &" for "screen -dmS ${BASENAME}" mono ${BINARYNAME} >/dev/null &" in your script and the correct $PID, that of the sleep process, was saved in the variable and acted upon.  This doesn't happen with screen for the reason I described above.

You might want to consider processing the output of "screen -list" in order to get at the pid of the detached process:

```
root@tutorial:/var/tmp# screen -dmS 'sleeper' sleep 2000
root@tutorial:/var/tmp# screen -list
There is a screen on:
    7089.sleeper    (07/02/2018 04:05:57 AM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.

root@tutorial:/var/tmp# ps axlww | grep 7089
5     0  7089     1  20   0  25672  2396 poll_s Ss   ?          0:00 SCREEN -dmS sleeper sleep 2000
4     0  7090  7089  20   0   5808   648 hrtime Ss+  pts/0      0:00 sleep 2000
0     0  7093  2607  20   0  12728  2192 pipe_w S+   ttyS1      0:00 grep 7089
```

From here your script could grab the pid of the sleeper.